# Controlling readiness of file descriptors

Tags: linux, select, io, named-pipes, fifo

I have a case where I have an incoming stream of complex messages which need some processing before they are passed in a simplified format to the actual handler.

I'd like to use a FIFO file descriptor, with one thread filling it from one end and another thread reading from the other. Now the kind of behavior I would like to have: the reading thread is waiting with `select()`, and I would like to guarantee that upon wakeup, there is a full package that can be read with a call to `read()`, i.e. I want to avoid having to reassemble packages because of fragmentation due to buffer sizes (the packages are guaranteed to be below the kernel-to-userspace buffer passing limit).

I want to know if there's a way of configuring the FIFO in such a way that I can manually define when the file descriptor is ready, i.e. when the producer has successfully written a full package, I'd like to have a way to signal to the reading end (via the file descriptor) that reading is ready. Is there a way to achieve this via `ioctl()` or is there some abstraction besides a FIFO that offers this behavior (in the Linux world)? (I know about `pthread` and condition variables, but I'd like the coupling between producer and consumer to be restricted to the shared file descriptor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a way of configuring the FIFO in such a way that I can manually define when the file descriptor is ready

There is no such way.

You have to.

- Define some sort of mesage framing. e.g. prepend the message length to the message, or separate them with a newline(given a newline can't occur within the message). In the case of newline separated messages, you might be able to wrap the filedescriptor in a FILE* and fgets() from that unless you're dependant on select() for multiplexing several streams or provide a timeout.
- Be prepared to handle `read()` or similar read 1 message, less than 1 message or more than 1 message - a fifo is just a stream of bytes so there's no message boundaries on that layer.
- Parse out the messages you've read according to how you decide to separate them.

Another alternative is to always send a fixed length message so you'll always know how much to read to get 1 message, or perhaps use AF_UNIX datagram sockets - as long as you can define a reasonable max size of a message.

Answer (score 2):

Try [socketpair()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html) instead of [pipe()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)/[mknod(S_IFIFO)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknod.html).

A socket pair can be made in domain `AF_UNIX` with type `SOCK_STREAM` (stream-based, your usage will need framing/reassembly), `SOCK_DGRAM` (datagram-based, will not be fragmented or merged), or `SOCK_SEQPACKET` (record-based, may be fragmented but not merged).